# using Ng-repeat with filter and duplicate record

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using angularjs. I have an array with records and level, and example of this is

```
[{id:1,level:1,partnerId:3},
{id:3,level:1,partnerId:''},
{id:5,level:1,partnerId:6},
{id:6,level:1,partnerId:''},
{id:7,level:2,partnerId:9},
{id:9,level:2,partnerId:''}]
```

I am filtering on `levelid`, and getting the correct display, except I am getting  single records that I do not want if there is already an element existing for them (an example of this is the items displayed in order would be
 `[1:3] [3] [5:6] [6] [7:9] [9])` but i would not want the `3,6,9` to display being there is one of them already existing. I am not sure how to check if it already displayed then do not display. is it possible to do with directive or `css` or `ng-if`? if a directive I am not even sure how to write it.

Comment: Please post the code you wrote

Comment: <li ng-repeat=" datax in individuals|filter:{level:'1'}|orderBy:'id'">                     
                        <a href=" #">{{datax.id}}</a><a href=" #">{{datax.partnerId}}</a>

Comment: No need for any directive, just prefilter data in controller.

Comment: <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat=" datax in individuals|filter:{level:'1'}|orderBy:'id'">                     
                        <a href=" #">{{datax.id}}</a><a href=" #">{{datax.partnerId}}</a>                                      
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    
                    <li ng-repeat=" datax in individuals|filter:{level:'2'}|orderBy:'id'">
                        <a href=" #">{{datax.id}}</a><a href=" #">{{datax.partnerId}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

Comment: can you give me an example of a controller for this? I am new to angularjs

Comment: You should format your code in the posts and in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a filter that gets the unique values. Something like this:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(collection, keyname) {
      var output = [], keys = [];

      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
          var key = item[keyname];
          if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(item);
          }
      });
      return output;
   };
});

<li ng-repeat="datax in individuals | unique: 'id'"></li>
```